# Firebase Cloud Messaging Questions About Overrided onNewToken Function

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have developed an Android application and when user run the application application does an initialization process while user see a splash screen. This initialization process includes database decryption and etc. I'm saving FCM token and other information in database.

I wrote "MyFirebaseMessagingService" which extends FirebaseMessagingService and overrides "onMessageReceived" and "onNewToken" functions. I can get notifications from FCM without any problem. I can get new token while application is running without any problem.

My question is: Is "onNewToken" function can be called when my application is not running(not initialized). It means that my application didn't do initilization process(does lots of things).

When "onNewToken" called my application should send this token to multiple servers and change some information in encrypted database.

If "onNewToken" function can be called when my application is not initialized, how can I know if my application is initialized or not in "onNewToken" function.

I'm a little confused about this topic. What's the best practice about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onNewToken` method is in a `Service` class, precisely because it may be called when the app is not actively being used. You should make sure that the code in `onNewToken` does not depend on any code from any activity having run.

The typical approach to this is to just store the token from the background service into your app's server-side list of FCM tokens.

Alternatively you can pass the token to your activity, so that it can pick it up when it becomes active again. I'd recommend against using this as the primary way to communicate tokens though, as you're likely to miss token updates here and thus won't be able to send notifications to the user until they start using the app again.